# Display attribute value from a given layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, expression

I am trying to display attribute values from various layers in a QGIS layout using a dynamic text expression. I've been able to calculate statistics for such layers (by following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NmdMnfwP3EQ); however, I want to display string attributes and not just statistics.

Is there an expression that allows me to display an attribute of choice from a layer of choice as dynamic text in a QGIS layout? The aim is to present snippets of information from various layers as text labels on the same sheet.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a combination of the `attribute` and the `get_feature` (or `get_feature_by_id`) functions.

`attribute` takes 2 arguments: a feature and the field from which you want the value. It returns the attribute value of a feature.
`get_feature` takes 3 arguments: the layer name, the field name, and the field value you wish to match. It returns a feature.

---

`get_feature_by_id` takes 2 arguments: the layer name and the feature id number

---

```sql
attribute(
    get_feature(
         'mylayer', 
         'myfieldname', 
         'myfieldvalue'),     -- match a feature using the field name and a specific value
    'mytargetfield'           -- get a specific attribute of the matched feature
)
```

For example, here I find the feature in `mylayer` that has a value of `1703` in the field `myfieldname`. The attribute of interest (`mytargetfield`) has the value `B`.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, apologies for the delay, but this is great! Thanks so much for your response.