# How to set up a filter in a value relation of a child of a parent-layer depending on attributes in parent layer

Tags: qgis, relation

I have a 1:n relation between (postgresql-) parent-layer "parentlayer" and a child-layer "childlayer" based on parent-layer-field `"pl_uuid"` referencing child-layer-field `"child_pl_uuid_ref"` and value-table (for value-relation-pull-down menu) "val_t" with a filter-criteria-field `"filter_val_t"`.
In parent-layer I have a field `"filter_pl"`.
In the child-layer I have a field `"my_selected_value"` with a value-relation. The list of selectable values of "val_t" shall be filtered depending on the **(unsaved)** values of `"filter_pl"` in parent layer (because this filter-value will be used in other sub-forms too).
Is there any way to set up this filter?

I tried several approaches like

1)
Create a virtual field `"virt_field_with_filter_pl"` in child-layer with `attribute(get_feature('parentlayer ', 'pl_uuid',  'child_pl_uuid_ref' ), 'filter_pl')`
and use this result in value relation as filter in value relation `"filter_val_t"=coalesce(current_value('virt_field_with_filter_pl'),0)`
or

2)
Set up a filter in the value-relation of the child-layer like `"filter_val_t"=coalesce(current_value('filter_pl'),'0')`

3)
Tried
[Get attribute value from parent layer to child layer sharing same uniqueID](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/447779/get-attribute-value-from-parent-layer-to-child-layer-sharing-same-uniqueid)